# Apache access log : multiple status code

Tags: apache, http

In Apache access.log, I am used to this kind of access log line:

```
127.0.0.1 - frank [10/Oct/2000:13:55:36 -0700] "GET /apache_pb.gif HTTP/1.0" 200 2326
```

I was checking some apache access logs this morning and found something I'm not used to:

```
192.168.1.10- - [20/Feb/2013:00:00:45 +0000] "POST /form/... 404 200 252 "-" "-" 435835
```

There are multiple status code. Does-it mean the request was sended multiple times (something like a failed/retry mechanism?

Comment: I'd suspect that either you got a POST request to `http://example.com/form/... 404 200 252 "-` or some other admin mangled with `LogFormat` or `CustomLog`.